# Moving Average from nested table using Oracle SQL

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to find the correct sql query based on the case below.

| customer_id | unit_id | NAV | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **16** | **1254** | **10** | **2020-05-01** |
| 17 | 1253 | 20 | 2020-05-02 |
| 18 | 1253 | 30 | 2020-05-03 |
| **16** | **1254** | **20** | **2020-05-02** |
| **16** | **1254** | **30** | **2020-05-03** |
| 17 | 1253 | 20 | 2020-05-02 |
| 17 | 1255 | 30 | 2020-05-03 |
| **16** | **1254** | **20** | **2020-05-04** |

From the table above, the AVERAGE_NAV can be found by moving average since the first date unit purchased. So, if I want to find moving average NAV for spesific data of **customer_id** and **unit_id** from table **ACCOUNTBALANCE**, I use this query below.

```
SELECT
    ACCBAL.CUSTOMER_ID,
    ACCBAL.UNITTRUST_ID,
    ACCBAL.INVACCT_ID,
    ACCBAL.NAV,
    AVG(ACCBAL.NAV)
        OVER (
            ORDER BY ACCBAL.BALANCEDATE
            RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
        ),
    ACCBAL.CREATED_DATE
FROM WMS_UT_ACCOUNTBAL ACCBAL
WHERE
    ACCBAL.CUSTOMER_ID=16 AND
    ACCBAL.UNITTRUST_ID=1254
```

you can see the picture of the query in the link below.
[query image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxC0R.png)

The result of the query is shown below.

| customer_id | unit_id | NAV | DATE | Average_NAV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 16 | 1254 | 10 | 2020-05-01 | 10 |
| 16 | 1254 | 20 | 2020-05-02 | 15 |
| 16 | 1254 | 30 | 2020-05-03 | 20 |
| 16 | 1254 | 20 | 2020-05-04 | 20 |

My question is, What is the query to find the average_NAV with all combined different customer_id and unit_id like this table below here.

| customer_id | unit_id | NAV | DATE | average_NAV |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **16** | **1254** | **10** | **2020-05-01** | **10** |
| *17* | *1253* | *20* | *2020-05-02* | *20* |
| 18 | 1253 | 30 | 2020-05-03 | 30 |
| **16** | **1254** | **20** | **2020-05-02** | **15** |
| **16** | **1254** | **30** | **2020-05-03** | **20** |
| *17* | *1253* | *20* | *2020-05-02* | *20* |
| 17 | 1255 | 30 | 2020-05-03 | 30 |
| **16** | **1254** | **20** | **2020-05-04** | **20** |

the average_NAV must be based on the query result from the same customer_id and unitrust_id start from the first purchase. you can see that for customer_id=17 and unit_id=1255 has average_NAV=30 same as NAV since it's first purchase with those spesific customer_id and unit_id  was 2020-05-03.
The main obstacle is how I can use where clause inside the outer SELECT because it's prohibited in oracle sql.

I have used CTE method (WITH) but still not what expected like below.

```
WITH ACCBAL (CUSTOMER_ID,UNITTRUST_ID,NAV, CREATED_DATE) AS
    (SELECT ACCBAL1.CUSTOMER_ID, ACCBAL1.UNITTRUST_ID,
            ACCBAL1.NAV, ACCBAL1.CREATED_DATE
     FROM WMS_UT_ACCOUNTBAL ACCBAL1),
    ACCBAL_AVERAGE_NAV (AVERAGE_NAV) AS
        (SELECT AVG(ACCBAL2.NAV) OVER
        (ORDER BY ACCBAL2.CREATED_DATE RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
            FROM WMS_UT_ACCOUNTBAL ACCBAL2
        WHERE ACCBAL2.UNITTRUST_ID=ACCBAL.UNITTRUST_ID
            AND ACCBAL2.CUSTOMER_ID=ACCBAL.CUSTOMER_ID)
SELECT * FROM ACCBAL,ACCBAL_AVERAGE_NAV;
```

The query above is not working because it gives error of invalid identidier in WHERE clause.

Anyone can help me? Truly Appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed question. Apart from the  solution for your original problem and answering for the correlated subquery in `from`: since Oracle 12c you may use ANSI lateral join by adding `lateral` keyword: `a left join lateral (select b.col from b where b.id = a.ref_id) on 1 = 1`. See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d08c6543d61c440681ccc8c5b8c65e87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can include the `PARTITION BY` clause before `ORDER BY`.
2. Tested on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=d6e7b9fc432038dd8c1b4319bb7a6ecd)

```
SELECT
    ACCBAL.CUSTOMER_ID,
    ACCBAL.UNITTRUST_ID,
    -- ACCBAL.INVACCT_ID,
    ACCBAL.NAV,
    ACCBAL.CREATED_DATE,
    AVG(ACCBAL.NAV)
        OVER (
            PARTITION BY ACCBAL.CUSTOMER_ID, ACCBAL.UNITTRUST_ID 
            ORDER BY ACCBAL.CREATED_DATE
        )
FROM WMS_UT_ACCOUNTBAL ACCBAL;
```

Comment: thank you so much man, it works. The result is what I expected :)